# jQuery.noConflict() not working in Umbraco backoffice

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, umbraco, umbraco8

I am trying to create package using angular and c#, I have a custom section in my umbraco backoffice and i am trying to display data using jQuery Datatable in that section, but i am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

I have tried to use `jQuery.noConflict()` but ain't working. What could be the possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your installation of the DataTable plug-in ?

And I think the proper way of using "no-conflict" is like this :

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(...).DataTable(...);
```

Comment: yes checked it's proper and also tried this one too